# onClickListener crashes program wont link to another activity android

Tags: android, eclipse

My Main Activity class is as follows

```
package com.example.barnight2;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView date;
private Button taxiButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();
    dateAndTime();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    taxiButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTaxi);

    taxiButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent taxiIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaxiActivity.class);
            startActivity(taxiIntent);   
        }
    });
}

public void dateAndTime() {

    date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDate);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    Date day = new Date();
    String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(day);

    date.setText(dayOfTheWeek);
}
}
```

then i have my second activity called the Taxi Activity

```
package com.example.barnight2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class TaxiActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_taxi);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.taxi, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my Manifest.xml i thought i had done everything perfectly but it seems to always crash upon start up of the app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.barnight2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" > 

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.barnight2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.barnight2.TaxiActivity" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                   
 </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

![image]http://i62.tinypic.com/16rma8.png

Comment: (1) If you have a crash, you should post a stack trace from logcat. (2) Only one of your activities should have the `android.intent.action.MAIN` intent-filter.

Comment: there is no need for intent filter for `TaxiActivity` since youahve explicit intents

Comment: Ive taken out the second intent-filter and still have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClassCastException
```

you're casting an object that it's not the same type you're trying to cast, so that's why it throw a `RunTimeException` with `ClassCastException`.

It should be:

```
taxiButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnTaxi);
```

Since you declared it as `ImageButton` in xml.

Comment: Thanks alot, easy problem when I look at it, just didn't realize the image button.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove :

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                   
</intent-filter>
```

from your activity com.example.barnight2.TaxiActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml